# Spring security 5 testing @WebMvcTest test keeps on giving 0302 response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2

I am writing a sample spring security 5 program. I am using AWS cognito as oauth2 provider. The flow that I am using is *authorization grant*.
When I run locally, everything works fine. My rest endpoints are properly secured and when I enter the credentials I am able to access the endpoints.

Now I want to test this controller using slice testing.

I have written a `@WebMvcTest` test for this, however, I keep getting 302 responses. In the logs, I see that the request gets redirected to cognito. My understanding was the request would not be sent to AWS during testing.
Please can someone shed light on why this must be happening or where I am going wrong.

**BirdController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class BirdController {

    @Autowired
    BirdService service;

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    List<Bird> getBirds(){
        return service.getAllBirds();
    }
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        private final String clientId;
        private final String logoutUrl;
    
        public WebSecurityConfiguration(@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.clientId}") String clientId,
                                 @Value("${cognito.logoutUrl}") String logoutUrl) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.logoutUrl = logoutUrl;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests(authorize ->
                            authorize.mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .and()
                    .logout();
                    
        }
    }
```

**BirdControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = BirdController.class)
public class BirdControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BirdService service;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    public void testGetAllBirds() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
```

I was expecting the test to pass the user is not authenticated however I get **302** response.

**Log snippet**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST=DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost/]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Location:"http://localhost/oauth2/authorization/cognito"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = http://localhost/oauth2/authorization/cognito
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :401
Actual   :302
 <Click to see difference>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
```

**AWS cognito configuration**

```
spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
          client:
            registration:
              cognito:
                clientId: XXXX
                clientSecret: XXXXX
                scope: openid
                redirectUriTemplate: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
                clientName: XXXX
            provider:
              cognito:
                issuerUri: XXXX
                user-name-attribute: cognito:username
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have already spent 3 days on it and tearing my hair apart. Have already looked up other questions but of no help.

Comment: When your application is running and you try to access a page with an anonymous user then you get redirected to the login page. Your tests are demonstrating exactly that behaviour. You wouldn't want your application to behave differently when tested, otherwise you are not testing the actual behaviour.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana How do I test it though? I don't want it to go to AWS cognito even for tests. I want it to mock it out automatically.

Comment: For the unauthenticated use case, it is enough to ensue that the user is being redirected. To test with a mock authenticated user, you can use a post processor, e.g `.with(oauth2Login())`. There are more examples in this section of the Spring Security reference docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#testing-oauth2-login

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana makes sense. Using ```WithMockUser```works fine as an authenticated user. For unauthenticated user, I am checking for redirection. Thanks for your help and inputs.